# setting up site in windows 7 for asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, configuration

Bought a Win 7 64-bit machine and installed vs2010 and things are fine.

Now i want to create a site in IIS for one of my asp.net application, so that i can access and get the site served from IIS rather than from WebDev.Webserver.exe.

Googled a lot, but haven't find a solution.  Can any one help me on this.

Comment: What do you need help with?  Installing IIS, or using IIS?

Comment: Is IIS installed? What edition of Window 7 are you running?

Comment: IIS is installed, the machine using windows premium and i need help to use IIS

Comment: Is there something wrong with the publish website option in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have IIS installed but [here](http://digitizor.com/2009/02/20/how-to-install-microsoft-iis-server-on-windows-7/) is how to do it. Provided you have the correct edition of Windows 7 (Professional or Ultimate).

Summary:

- Start > Control Panel > Programs
- click on Turn Windows features on or off.
- Check the box for 'Internet Information Services (IIS)

Once installed you can follow the steps included on the [microsoft website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350.aspx). This should get you up and running.

Summary:

- Open IIS Manager.
- In the Connections pane, right-click the Sites node in the tree, and then click Add Web Site.
- In the Add Web Site dialog box, type a name for your Web site in the Web site name box.
- Click Select if you want to select a different application pool than the one listed in the Application Pool box. In the Select
  Application Pool dialog box, select an application pool from the
  Application Pool list and then click OK.
- In the Physical path box, type the physical path of the Web site's folder, or click the browse button (...) to navigate the file system
  to find the folder.
- If you do not have to make any changes to the site, and you want the Web site to be immediately available, select the Start Web site
  immediately check box.
- Click OK.